# Morse code in java using HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I try to implement Morse code translator in Java, using as little code as possible, but in my program i get an error, cause hashmap is out of border. Is it possible to assign size of map equals to length of string, that i input? But no less than 26 for not just putting out alphabetical characters. Thanks

```
    String a = reader.readLine();

    Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<>();
    words.put("s", "***"); //only two characters still
    words.put("o", "---");



    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) 
    {   
        String checker = Character.toString(a.charAt(i));

        if(checker.equals(words.keySet().toArray()[i])) 
        {
            System.out.print(words.values().toArray()[i]+" ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use words.get(checker)

Comment: can you clarify on the exact error that you are getting.. its not clear from `cause hashmap is out of border`..

Comment: On a side note, if the map consists of `Character` based mapping. Use a `Map<Character,String>` instead.

Comment: @redflar3 He means "out of order".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(checker.equals(words.keySet().toArray()[i])) 
    {
        System.out.print(words.values().toArray()[i]+" ");
    }
```

Change this to:

```
if(words.get(checker) != null)
    System.out.print(words.get(checker) + " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to see if the current letter is contained within the map, if it is then you can grab the corresponding mapping for it within the words hashmap.

```
   String a = reader.nextLine();

    Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<>();
    words.put("s", "***"); //only two characters still
    words.put("o", "---");

    String translated = "";

    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) 
    {   
        String checker = Character.toString(a.charAt(i));

        if(words.containsKey(checker)) 
        {
            translated += words.get(checker);
        }
        else{
            translated += checker;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Input: " + a + ", Morse: " + translated);
```

Output

```
sos
Input: sos, Morse: ***---***
sor
Input: sor, Morse: ***---r
```

This will convert all the letters the map knows about, for those it doesn't it will not change.